# Как пишутся частицы?

Tags: орфография, частицы

Как пишутся со словами частицы вроде "бы", "кое" и т. д.: слитно или раздельно?

Comment: То, либо, нибудь, кое ... Звучит как мелодия, которую я выучил с 5-го класса общеобразовательной школы. Так на всю жизнь и осело в памяти. Как важно в нужный момент выбрать правильный методический приём учителю. В данном случае на заучивание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раздельно со словами пишутся частицы: **бы, же, ли (ль)**.
Примеры: *это же, как бы, ни это ль*.

Через дефис пишутся: **то, либо, нибудь, ка (тка), де, с**.
Примеры: *кто-то, где-то, как-нибудь, постой-ка, это-де, нуте-с*.

Если частица ***кое*** отделяется от слова другим словом, то она пишется отдельно.
Пример: *кое в чём*.

Answer (score 0):

Частицы *бы, ли, же, б, ль, ж* всегда пишутся раздельно. Частицы *кое, то либо, нибудь, так таки* - через дефис.

Answer (score 0):

таки пишется без дефиса. С дефисом  - после глаголов ("взял-таки") и еще в двух случаях: "всё-таки", "так-таки".